# How feedburner knows what is the content of a page?

Tags: html, rss, html-parsing

I Would like to know how feedburner knows what is the title and content of a page, are there any mandatory tag or they just implement an algorithm for each version of worpress, blogger , etc?

Comment: RSS/Atom feeds have title and content elements.

Answer (score 1):

They just read the feed from your blog and add a few elements of their own and pass it on. The blogging software does most of the work for them.

Comment: so, if I have just the link to the post, how can I get just the "post content" ?